# why I have some duplicate rows in merge function?

Tags: r, dataframe

Why when I merge 2 data sets, some duplicate rows appear? Here is  example:

```
dput(head(OverLaps))
OverLap<-structure(list(
               SAMPN = c("   19", "   19", "   19", "   78","  102", "  102"), 
               id = 1:6,
               overlap = c("3", NA, "1", NA, NA, NA),
               PERNO = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                 .Label = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
                 class = "factor")),
               row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

comp<-structure(list(
               SAMPN = c("   19", "   19", "   19", "   19","   78", "  102"), 
               MODE1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L),
                  .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"),
               PERNO = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L),
                  .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
                  class = "factor"),
               PLANO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L),
                  .Label = c(" 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", 
                  "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
                  "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "27"), class = "factor"),
               loop = structure(c(2L,2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L),
                  .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"),
                  class = "factor")),
               row.names = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 69L, 125L),
               class = "data.frame")
```

I merge them by the following

```
OverLaps1<-merge( OverLaps,comp, all.y = TRUE)
```

if you look at output , id column in OverLaps is unique for each row. but in merge I have several rows for same id, it duplicates some rows.

```
  SAMPN PERNO id overlap MODE1
1    19     1  1       3     2
2    19     2  2    <NA>     2
3    19     2  2    <NA>     2
4    19     2  2    <NA>     3
5    19     2  3       1     2
6    19     2  3       1     2
```

structure:

```
OverLaps

str(OverLaps)
'data.frame':   1676 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ SAMPN   : chr  "   19" "   19" "   19" "   19" ...
 $ id      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ overlap : chr  "4" NA NA "1" ...
 $ PERNO   : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
```

comp:

```
str(comp[1:5])
    'data.frame':   1763 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ SAMPN: chr  "   19" "   19" "   19" "   19" ...
     $ MODE1: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 3 4 2 2 2 2 4 ...
     $ PERNO: Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
     $ PLANO: Factor w/ 24 levels " 2"," 3"," 4",..: 1 1 4 5 1 1 7 8 9 2 ...
     $ loop : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
```

Comment: Also, you have PERNO variable in both data frames in your example code, but not in the structure of OverLaps. That is why you are getting the issue of not being able to join on PERNO.

Comment: I have it in OverLaps just deleted before using structure to check if it changes anything. but I need it, would you like me to add it and do str again?

Comment: Clarify what exactly is in the data frames and post their structure. Then post an example of the desired end product. Do this even if you have got it for others in the future and I can clarify my answer likewise.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have two non-unique keys in both dataframes.  So when you join them, you create duplicates.

I do not know which dataframe is OverLaps or which one is comp, but if we assume OverLaps is the first one and comp the second one, we can use the `dplyr` package from R and create a left_join

```
library(dplyr)
OverLaps$SAMPN<-as.character(OverLaps$SAMPN) # need to have the same type of variable across the dataframes.
OverLaps1<-left_join(OverLaps,comp,by=c('SAMPN'='SAMPN','PERNO'='PERNO')) # these are the overlapping keys in each dataframe.

   SAMPN id overlap PERNO MODE1 PLANO loop
1     19  1       3     1     2     2    2
2     19  2    <NA>     2     2     2    2
3     19  2    <NA>     2     2     5    2
4     19  2    <NA>     2     3     6    3
5     19  3       1     2     2     2    2
6     19  3       1     2     2     5    2
7     19  3       1     2     3     6    3
8     78  4    <NA>     1     4     2    2
9    102  5    <NA>     1     2     2    2
10   102  6    <NA>     1     2     2    2
```

However, if you only have SAMPN across each data frame as your structure code says, then you want to use the following

```
library(dplyr)
    OverLaps$SAMPN<-as.character(OverLaps$SAMPN) # need to have the same type of variable across the dataframes.
    OverLaps1<-left_join(OverLaps,comp,by=c('SAMPN'='SAMPN'))
```

Comment: Error: Can't join on 'PERNO' x 'PERNO' because of incompatible types (factor / hms/difftime)

Comment: Can you provide some detail on the structure of your dataframe? Because it worked fine for me.

Comment: how I can do that?

Comment: str(dataframe). So in your case it would be str(OverLap) and str(comp)

Comment: str(OverLaps)
'data.frame': 1676 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ SAMPN   : Factor w/ 3724 levels "    4","    8",..: 4 4 4 4 17 28 28 28 28 30 ...
 $ id      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ time_ARR: chr  "16 :3" "05 :1" "15 :2" "16 :2" ...
 $ time_Dep: chr  "16 :3" "05 :3" "15 :3" "16 :3" ...
 $ overlap : chr  "4" NA NA "1" ...

Comment: 'data.frame': 1763 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ SAMPN: chr  "   19" "   19" "   19" "   19" ...
 $ MODE1: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 3 4 2 2 2 2 4 ...
 $ PERNO: Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ PLANO: Factor w/ 24 levels " 2"," 3"," 4",..: 1 1 4 5 1 1 7 8 9 2 ...
 $ loop : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...

Comment: add this to the question.

Comment: but again it gives me several rows for same SAMPN, PERNO and id in OverLaps

Comment: It will do that if you have different values for MODE1, PLANO, and loop. A join will match the keys between data frames. If there is non-unique info in the rows, then those non-unique rows will appear.